# Is one map per line in hadoop grep example justified?

Tags: hadoop, grep

I'm a hadoop newbie. While going through hadoop example for a similar implementation in a rather large cluster, I was wondering why the grep example that comes along with hadoop code, why do they have one map per line ?

I know that it makes sense from the perspective of a teaching example. But in a   real hadoop cluster, where a grep is to be done on an industry(1 PB log files) scale, is it worth creating a map() per line? Is the overhead of creating a map(), and the tasktracker keeping track of it and the associated bandwidth usage justified if we create a map per line?

Comment: You should grab a book about Hadoop first, you don't really know what the difference between a mapper, a task, a line and a job is. Nor do you know what a namenode does x.x

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'm an absolute newbie. I did some basic reading and modified the question a bit. Am I still wildly wrong?

Comment: Yes, map is just a method call. A mapper task (a real jvm) will be spawned for each input block, then on this block of data `map` will be called for every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate Map task will not be done for every line; You are confusing the programming model for MapReduce with the execution model.

When you implement a mapper, you are implementing a function that operates on a single piece of data (let's say a line in a log file). The hadoop framework takes care of essentially looping over all your log files, reading each line, and passing that line into your mapper.

MapReduce allows you to write your code in such a way that you are dealing with an abstraction that's useful: a line in a log file is a good example. The advantage of using something like Hadoop is that it will take care of the parallelization of this code for you: It will distribute your program out to a bunch of processes that will execute it (TaskTracker) and those TaskTrackers will read chunks llof data from the HDFS nodes that store it (Data Nodes).